# How to convert a char array to a char pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a piece of code, that will give me an character array.
I want to give this array to a function that expects a character pointer.
When I enter this array to the function, it results in an segmentation fault when I try to run the program.

This works fine.

```
char* buffer = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sum>  <part>55</part>  <part>6</part>  <part>*</part></sum>";

long output = calcXML(buffer);
```

When I try to make an array of it it will give me a segmentation fault

```
char buffer[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sum>  <part>55</part>  <part>6</part>  <part>*</part></sum>";

long output = calcXML(buffer);
```

Also when I try to make a pointer out of the array, the same segmentation fault occurs.

```
char buffer[] = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><sum>  <part>55</part>  <part>6</part>  <part>*</part></sum>";
char *ptrBuffer = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) + 1);
ptrBuffer = &buffer[0];

long output = calcXML(ptrBuffer);
```

How can I solve this?

Edit:
The function `calcXML(char *xml)` will pass the xml parameter to the function `xmlParseDoc()`. This is a function of the [libxml library](http://xmlsoft.org/)

Comment: XY problem - your issue is not with passing a var char array vs char pointer, but with what the `calcXML` is trying to do with with that parameter.

Comment: NB: `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ to be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first one works because it's returning the address of a string literal. String literals are global, i.e. the memory that holds the characters is initialized as the program starts up, and the location doesn't change.
- The second one should work, but there's too little information for it to work.
- The third one is broken, it overwrities the memory allocated by `malloc()` with the address of a local array. Disregarding that it shbould work, but just as in case two there's too little information.

Further, the `malloc()` call itself in the third case is not correct.

It computes the size as `strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char) + 1`, but since the termination character is also a character, it doesn't make sense to avoid scaling the allocation for that. So, it "should" be `(strlen(buffer) + 1) * sizeof(char)`. But then again `sizeof (char)` is always 1, so the scaling is totally pointless, i.e. it should just be `strlen(buffer) + 1`. Again, the code is broken since the return value from `malloc()` is then immediately overwritten, but still.

Comment: But the pointer is *passed* to another function (calcXML), not *returned*. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Without the surrounding code it is hard to tell, but since version 2 is legal C-Syntax, I think that you are probably returning this array from a function, which means it will cease to exist after the function exits. De-referencing a pointer to it will very likely segfault. This does not happen in the first case, since string literals are hard-coded and immutable, so the reference remains valid.

Using the idea behind the third approach is in fact also correct here, but you are doing it the wrong way. You should allocate the memory and then either use `snprinft`, `strncpy` or `memcpy` in combination with the string literal to copy the string into the buffer. Right now you are discarding the pointer to the `malloced` memory, which will result in a leak. You set the pointer to the beginning of the automatically allocated array, so once that is out of scope de-referencing a pointer to it will probably segfault again for the reasons explained with regard to version 2.

Comment: for #3, `strdup` would suffice!

Answer (score 1):

The first code will initialiase `buffer` to point directly to a static string in the `text` segment of the code.  Modifying that string would be undefined behaviour.

The second code will initialise `buffer` with a *copy* of the static string, where that copy resides on the stack.  The copy will disappear when the function exits.

The third version doesn't work - you never put a copy of the string in the allocated buffer and then you go and overwrite that new pointer with the same stack-based copy created in version 2.  A simpler call would simply be:

```
char *ptrBuffer = strdup(buffer);
```

not forgetting to then `free()` the resulting copy at some later point.

As for why #2 doesn't work - we can't tell given the detail provided.  It'll depend on something within the implementation of `calcXML`, or perhaps on code omitted from your question.